# why jvm use 4 byte to save a reference in 64-bit env?

Tags: java

I found that jvm use 4 byte to save a reference point to a object in **64-bit env**.

I do not understand that how to deal with when application has more than 2^32 objects?

who can describe this case?

Comment: I don't think many applications do

Comment: Try creating too may objects and see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

`32-bit` JVMs do use `32` bits for references, but `64-bit` JVMs can use `64-bits` for references.

Before you exhaust the 2<sup>32</sup> limit on number of references on a `32-bit` JVM, you will have got an `OutOfMemoryError` (you can't have much more than `2GB` of heap on a `32-bit` JVM, regardless of the available RAM).

On a `64-bit JVM`, you can create more than 2<sup>32</sup> objects, assuming you have enough memory to store them.

Note that some 64-bit JVMs might use 32 bit pointers ([CompressedOops flag on hotspot](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops)) for performance purposes.

Comment: I test for it in 64 bit env,there is really 4 byte to point to an obejct

Comment: Under 3.5gbs it will use the `compressed oops`. This will compress the reference sizes to 4 bytes even with 64 bit JVMs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `x64` JVM. It uses `8` bytes.

However, if you have 2<sup>32</sup> objects, each of them is minimum 40 bytes... It doesn't fit into `4GB` memory anyway.

Comment: Minimum size of 40 bytes per object? Are you sure/do you have a source? From what I recall, the GC header is at most three, sometimes two words, so even if we ignore out empty classes the minimum object size should be roughly four words = 16 bytes.

Comment: a `new Object()` needs 12 bytes of memory on hotspot, aligned to 16 bytes.

Comment: Ok, you are right, seems 40 is too much. But obviously more that 16, you should add up memory which requires to save references to the objects so that they are not just garbage collected. Anyway, even 20 bytes is at least 20 times more than x32 memory space able to hold.